# Simple PDE example - why are limits included in the solution integral?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the book "An introduction to PDES", by Pinchover and Rubinstein, an example problem is

$$u_x =c_0 u(x,y) + c_1(x,y)$$

where $c_0$ is a constant and the initial value
$$u(0,y)=y$$
is given. The authors then jump the the "obvious" solution
$$ u(x,y) = e^{c_0 x}\left[\int_0^x e^{-c_0 \xi}c_1(\xi,y)d\xi + y\right]$$

Is it true that the solution without the initial value is

$$ u(x,y) = e^{c_0 x} \int e^{-c_0x}c_1(x,y) dx + e^{c_0x}f(y)$$
and that the initial value condition can be written
$$u(0,y) = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-c_0 x} c_1(x,y) dx + f(y) =y$$
and hence we know that
$$f(y)=y, \hspace{1cm} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-c_0x}c_1(x,y) dx = 0$$
and that is why we can include those limits in the solution-integral ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true, but you have some unnecessary freedom in your solution. You have an arbitrary constant of integration for the first term (which is a particular solution of the equation) plus an arbitrary function in the second term, which represents the general solution to the homogeneous equation. It would be equally general to say that the general solution is
$$
u(x,y)=e^{c_0x}f(y)+e^{c_0x}\int\limits_0^xe^{-c_0s}c_1(s,y)\,ds
$$
and then your initial condition implies $f(y)=y$. Of course you can replace the lower limit in the integral by any real number (that changes your $f(y)$ by some constant). Setting it equal to $-\infty$ is not safe because you do not know whether the improper integral converges (this will depend on the behavior of $c_1(\cdot, y)$) In any case, you cannot set the integral 
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^0e^{-c_0s}c_1(s,y)\,ds
$$
equal to zero, since all the functions are given and fixed. All you have to play with is $f(y)$, which is equal to $y$ if you set the lower limit in the integral equal to zero.

Comment: Can you express the general solution in terms of a definite integral without knowing u(0,y) ? E.g., if you were given u(a, y) instead... would the lower limit be a ?

Comment: Yes, you can as long as you have your "arbitrary function of $y$" somewhere else. Your general solution has two pieces: one particular solution of the equation and the general solution of the homogeneous equation. That particular solution is not unique, you can add to it any solution of the homogeneous equation. The advantage of choosing the lower limit $=0$ is that it is equal to zero at $x=0$, for any $y$ and therefore $f(y)=y$. If you were given $u(a,0)$ it would be convenient to choose $a$ as your lower limit.